# Arquillian/JUnit Fails to Run in JBoss Tools Generated Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I am using Eclipse Kepler with JBoss 7.1.1 and I use JBoss Tools Central to generate the "Java EE Web Project" template project.  The project generates successfully and runs fine.  However, after starting the server, when I click on the project and select Run as JUnit Test I have a couple of problems/issues:

1) The console shows 'deployed "test.war" '.  But neither the console nor the Kepler JUnit View show any test information at all.  As a test, I altered the following line in the auto-generated code for MemberRegistrationTest.java:
assertNotNull(newMember.getId());
to be
assertNull(newMember.getId());

to force an assert.  However, I get no output in the console nor in the JUnit view showing this assert.  As far as I can tell, the Run as JUnit Test is either not running at all or it is failing to display any results.

2) Each time I Run as Junit Test I get one or more folders added to \standalone\data\content, each of which is named with a two digit hex character (e.g., "87") and that folder contains another folder with a 38 hex character name (e.g. "ed8525e1a637334f002e6c4ebec047445b0ec3").  In that folder is a file named "content" that is about 750k in size.  Every time I run a test I get more of these folders and they are never cleaned up.  Further, in The JBoss config file standalone.xml I discovered that the following has been added:

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="test.war" runtime-name="test.war">
        <content sha1="87ed8525e1a637334f002e6c4ebec047445b0ec3"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

where the "87ed8525e1a637334f002e6c4ebec047445b0ec3" corresponds to the folder "87" and the subfolder "ed8525e1a637334f002e6c4ebec047445b0ec3" (for example).  (It appears that the 40 char SHA1 hash is used to name these two folders.)  If I delete the project and ask for it to be removed from disk I get an error stating that "An exception has been caught while processing the refactoring 'Delete Resource' and Details shows that it could not delete the Project folder.  Then, when I restart Kepler and try to recreate the Project with the same name I get the error that it already exists.  If I then shutdown Kelper I get an error that "the project cannot be updated."  Also, the  block stays in standalone.xml.

Can someone explain why this unaltered project "right out of the box" is "failing" to test and is messing up Kepler's Project management when I try to delete it?

Thank you.
Al

Answer (score -1):

I am encountering the same problem.  Based on my preliminary fiddling with test cases, it appears that Arquillian 1.1.4.Final is silently hanging if the shrinkwrap deployment does not include all required classes.  My symptom was that the test run just hung indefinitely after the "deployed application" message. In at least one case, reviewing the test code and adding to the shrinkwrap a couple of classes that were mentioned in the test code but had not been added to the shrinkwrap, caused the problem to go away.   I will update when I learn more.